# Scheme image manipulation

Tags: image, functional-programming, scheme

Is there any easy way to manipulate images in Scheme?

I want to save a bitmap (represented as lists in some way) to some lossless image format (for instance, say png).

I'm using mit-scheme, but I can switch to any other (free) interpreter, since my code is standard for now.

Answer (score 2):

In [Racket](http://racket-lang.org), you can use this package:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html):

> The image teachpack provides a number of basic image construction functions, along with combinators for building more complex images out of existing images. Basic images include various polygons, ellipses and circles, and text, as well as bitmaps. Existing images can be rotated, scaled, flipped, and overlaid on top of each other.